# How to quote a previous paper with different authors?

Tags: citation-style

I am writing a paper that builds on a previous one, where another author was present. How should I quote the previous one?
For example:
"In a previous paper [1] we proposed ..."
or
"In a previous paper [1] we and a collaborator proposed ..."

What is the correct one both scientifically and linguistically?

Comment: "In paper [1] it was proposed that..."/"It was proposed in [1]..."